# Create an array of the time, in seconds, since the start of the month at which each hourly reading was taken

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am running the following code and I am getting a 66.7% score, which means there is something wrong with it. Running the len gives 744 elements (31x24), so that part of the question has been looked at already. I don't think I have the stop and step parts of the method wrong.

> The first reading was taken at the first instant of December 2015
>   (midnight on December 1st) and each subsequent reading was taken
>   exactly 1 hour after the last.
>
> Question 1.1.5. Create an array of the time, in seconds, since the
>   start of the month at which each hourly reading was taken. Name it
>   collection_times.
>
> Hint 1: There were 31 days in December, which is equivalent to ( 31×24
>   ) hours or ( 31×24×60×60 ) seconds. So your array should have  31×24 
>   elements in it.
>
> Hint 2: The len function works on arrays, too. If your
>   collection_times isn't passing the tests, check its length and make
>   sure it has  31×24  elements.

```
import numpy as np

collection_times = np.arange(0,44640,60)
collection_times
len(collection_times)

array([    0,    60,   120,   180,   240,   300,   360,   420,   480,
     540,   600,   660,   720,   780,   840,   900,   960,  1020,
    1080,  1140,  1200,  1260,  1320,  1380,  1440,  1500,  1560,
    1620,  1680,  1740,  1800,  1860,  1920,  1980,  2040,  2100,
    2160,  2220,  2280,  2340,  2400,  2460,  2520,  2580,  2640,
    2700,  2760,  2820,  2880,  2940,  3000,  3060,  3120,  3180,
    3240,  3300,  3360,  3420,  3480,  3540,  3600,  3660,  3720,
    3780,  3840,  3900,  3960,  4020,  4080,  4140,  4200,  4260,
    4320,  4380,  4440,  4500,  4560,  4620,  4680,  4740,  4800,
    4860,  4920,  4980,  5040,  5100,  5160,  5220,  5280,  5340,
    5400,  5460,  5520,  5580,  5640,  5700,  5760,  5820,  5880,
    5940,  6000,  6060,  6120,  6180,  6240,  6300,  6360,  6420,
    6480,  6540,  6600,  6660,  6720,  6780,  6840,  6900,  6960,
    7020,  7080,  7140,  7200,  7260,  7320,  7380,  7440,  7500,
    7560,  7620,  7680,  7740,  7800,  7860,  7920,  7980,  8040,
    8100,  8160,  8220,  8280,  8340,  8400,  8460,  8520,  8580,
    8640,  8700,  8760,  8820,  8880,  8940,  9000,  9060,  9120,
    9180,  9240,  9300,  9360,  9420,  9480,  9540,  9600,  9660,
    9720,  9780,  9840,  9900,  9960, 10020, 10080, 10140, 10200,
   10260, 10320, 10380, 10440, 10500, 10560, 10620, 10680, 10740,
   10800, 10860, 10920, 10980, 11040, 11100, 11160, 11220, 11280,
   11340, 11400, 11460, 11520, 11580, 11640, 11700, 11760, 11820,
   11880, 11940, 12000, 12060, 12120, 12180, 12240, 12300, 12360,
   12420, 12480, 12540, 12600, 12660, 12720, 12780, 12840, 12900,
   12960, 13020, 13080, 13140, 13200, 13260, 13320, 13380, 13440,
   13500, 13560, 13620, 13680, 13740, 13800, 13860, 13920, 13980,
   14040, 14100, 14160, 14220, 14280, 14340, 14400, 14460, 14520,
   14580, 14640, 14700, 14760, 14820, 14880, 14940, 15000, 15060,
   15120, 15180, 15240, 15300, 15360, 15420, 15480, 15540, 15600,
   15660, 15720, 15780, 15840, 15900, 15960, 16020, 16080, 16140,
   16200, 16260, 16320, 16380, 16440, 16500, 16560, 16620, 16680,
   16740, 16800, 16860, 16920, 16980, 17040, 17100, 17160, 17220,
   17280, 17340, 17400, 17460, 17520, 17580, 17640, 17700, 17760,
   17820, 17880, 17940, 18000, 18060, 18120, 18180, 18240, 18300,
   18360, 18420, 18480, 18540, 18600, 18660, 18720, 18780, 18840,
   18900, 18960, 19020, 19080, 19140, 19200, 19260, 19320, 19380,
   19440, 19500, 19560, 19620, 19680, 19740, 19800, 19860, 19920,
   19980, 20040, 20100, 20160, 20220, 20280, 20340, 20400, 20460,
   20520, 20580, 20640, 20700, 20760, 20820, 20880, 20940, 21000,
   21060, 21120, 21180, 21240, 21300, 21360, 21420, 21480, 21540,
   21600, 21660, 21720, 21780, 21840, 21900, 21960, 22020, 22080,
   22140, 22200, 22260, 22320, 22380, 22440, 22500, 22560, 22620,
   22680, 22740, 22800, 22860, 22920, 22980, 23040, 23100, 23160,
   23220, 23280, 23340, 23400, 23460, 23520, 23580, 23640, 23700,
   23760, 23820, 23880, 23940, 24000, 24060, 24120, 24180, 24240,
   24300, 24360, 24420, 24480, 24540, 24600, 24660, 24720, 24780,
   24840, 24900, 24960, 25020, 25080, 25140, 25200, 25260, 25320,
   25380, 25440, 25500, 25560, 25620, 25680, 25740, 25800, 25860,
   25920, 25980, 26040, 26100, 26160, 26220, 26280, 26340, 26400,
   26460, 26520, 26580, 26640, 26700, 26760, 26820, 26880, 26940,
   27000, 27060, 27120, 27180, 27240, 27300, 27360, 27420, 27480,
   27540, 27600, 27660, 27720, 27780, 27840, 27900, 27960, 28020,
   28080, 28140, 28200, 28260, 28320, 28380, 28440, 28500, 28560,
   28620, 28680, 28740, 28800, 28860, 28920, 28980, 29040, 29100,
   29160, 29220, 29280, 29340, 29400, 29460, 29520, 29580, 29640,
   29700, 29760, 29820, 29880, 29940, 30000, 30060, 30120, 30180,
   30240, 30300, 30360, 30420, 30480, 30540, 30600, 30660, 30720,
   30780, 30840, 30900, 30960, 31020, 31080, 31140, 31200, 31260,
   31320, 31380, 31440, 31500, 31560, 31620, 31680, 31740, 31800,
   31860, 31920, 31980, 32040, 32100, 32160, 32220, 32280, 32340,
   32400, 32460, 32520, 32580, 32640, 32700, 32760, 32820, 32880,
   32940, 33000, 33060, 33120, 33180, 33240, 33300, 33360, 33420,
   33480, 33540, 33600, 33660, 33720, 33780, 33840, 33900, 33960,
   34020, 34080, 34140, 34200, 34260, 34320, 34380, 34440, 34500,
   34560, 34620, 34680, 34740, 34800, 34860, 34920, 34980, 35040,
   35100, 35160, 35220, 35280, 35340, 35400, 35460, 35520, 35580,
   35640, 35700, 35760, 35820, 35880, 35940, 36000, 36060, 36120,
   36180, 36240, 36300, 36360, 36420, 36480, 36540, 36600, 36660,
   36720, 36780, 36840, 36900, 36960, 37020, 37080, 37140, 37200,
   37260, 37320, 37380, 37440, 37500, 37560, 37620, 37680, 37740,
   37800, 37860, 37920, 37980, 38040, 38100, 38160, 38220, 38280,
   38340, 38400, 38460, 38520, 38580, 38640, 38700, 38760, 38820,
   38880, 38940, 39000, 39060, 39120, 39180, 39240, 39300, 39360,
   39420, 39480, 39540, 39600, 39660, 39720, 39780, 39840, 39900,
   39960, 40020, 40080, 40140, 40200, 40260, 40320, 40380, 40440,
   40500, 40560, 40620, 40680, 40740, 40800, 40860, 40920, 40980,
   41040, 41100, 41160, 41220, 41280, 41340, 41400, 41460, 41520,
   41580, 41640, 41700, 41760, 41820, 41880, 41940, 42000, 42060,
   42120, 42180, 42240, 42300, 42360, 42420, 42480, 42540, 42600,
   42660, 42720, 42780, 42840, 42900, 42960, 43020, 43080, 43140,
   43200, 43260, 43320, 43380, 43440, 43500, 43560, 43620, 43680,
   43740, 43800, 43860, 43920, 43980, 44040, 44100, 44160, 44220,
   44280, 44340, 44400, 44460, 44520, 44580])

744
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking for hourly readings, rather that taking readings every minute. It should work if you change your code to:

```
collection_times = np.arange(0,44640,3600)`
```